# How to avoid newlines output in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; 
do 
    (printf %s "$(date '+%A %W %Y %X')";    echo -n ", " ;  printf %s "$(ps -eo pcpu,pmem,comm | grep statsd)") >> tope.txt;
    sleep 2;
done
```

What I want is the output of this command be entered into tope.txt like this:

```
Friday 20 2015 11:28:21,  0.0  0.4 /usr/libexec/systemstatsd
```

but what I get is output like this in multiline. :

```
Friday 20 2015 11:28:21
,
  0.0  0.4 /usr/libexec/systemstatsd
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that's the **exact** script you are using? Because I don't see how it would generate that output. Also if that `grep` ever matches more than one thing you'll get newlines you aren't expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single printf statement.

```
while true
do 
    printf '%s, %s\n' "$(date '+%A %W %Y %X')" \
                      "$(ps -eo pcpu,pmem,comm | grep statsd)" >> tope.txt
    sleep 2;
done
```

You may also want to consider moving the file redirect outside the loop to avoid repeat `open`s in a loop.

Comment: I agree the single printf approach is better but why was his original not working?

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't know. `printf() { shift; echo "$@"; }`? There's no sane explanation.